# How to remove specific http response codes from access.log in jboss 5

Tags: configuration, jboss, jboss-web

Is there a way to remove specific http response codes from jbosses-5 `access.log` ?

Unluckily http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/config/valve.html was not really helpful.